# Abstracting component-methods in Component Based frameworks & Redux

Tags: reactjs, vue.js, redux, vue-component, vuex

In Either React, or Vue, I'm running into the following scenario: Similar Components, like for example a Modal Dialog (form) that handles Logging in, and a Modal Dialog handling Registration, have the following in common:

1. a button that handles closing the modal dialog
2. a button that when clicked performs validation of the form
3. an error message shown depending on the validation outcome.

Given the above, I assume there could be a base  Component or  component, in which props are passed which define its' visual style and functionality.

My question is two-fold:

1/ When Using the Redux (Vuex) architecture, are you expected to hold a separate state for each of those versions of the Modal Dialog? and
2/ How would you practically avoid code repetition?

e.g.

```
state: {
    items: [
    ],
    loginDialog: {
      isValid: true,
      isVisible: false,
      errorMsg: '',
    },
    signupDialog: {
      isValid: true,
      isVisible: false,
      errorMsg: '',
    }, 
}
```

In my mind, the Redux architecture of being able to debug every bit of your application separately, comes often in conflict with the component/containered way of building.

Below a Vuex component (not strictly necessary for the question) that illustrates the problem:

```
<template>
  <v-dialog width="600"
            v-model="isVisible"
            persistent>
    <v-card>
      <v-card-title>
        <span class="headline">Register</span>
      </v-card-title>
      <v-card-text>
        <v-form v-model="valid">
// form here           
        </v-form>
      </v-card-text>
      <v-alert v-if="!signupDialog.isValid" error value="true">
        {{ signupDialog.errorMsg }}
      </v-alert>
      <v-card-actions>
        <v-spacer></v-spacer>
        <v-btn class="blue--text darken-1"
               flat
               @click="toggleDialog()">Close
        </v-btn>
        <v-btn class="blue--text darken-1"
               flat
               @click="submitRegisterForm(signup)">Save
        </v-btn>
      </v-card-actions>
    </v-card>
  </v-dialog>
</template>

<script>
  import { mapState } from 'vuex';

  export default {
    name: 'signup',
    computed: {
      ...mapState([
        'signupDialog',
      ]),
      isVisible: {
        get() {
          return this.$store.state.signupDialog.isVisible;
        },
        set() {
          this.toggleDialog();
        },
      },
    },
    methods: {
      toggleDialog() {
        this.$store.dispatch('toggleDialog', { dialog: 'signupDialog' });
      },
    },
  };
</script>
```

Comment: Sounds like a job for [mixins](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html).

Answer (score 0):

I face this in my past project and I create 1 function to init state to reduce code repetition:

```
function initDialogState: () => ({
  isValid: true,
  isVisible: false,
  errorMsg: '',
})

state: {
    items: [
    ],

    dialog: {
      login: initDialogState(),
      signup: initDialogState(),
   }
}
```

then your mutation can be (I will create an example in Vuex structure):

```
setDialog(state, { kind, type, value }) {
  Vue.set(state[kind], type, value)
}
```

Comment: Wondering if we could just use `dialog: { isValid: true, isVisible: true }` somehow

Comment: But how can you know it's value for login or signup? Of course, you can merge login and signup to 1 dialog then add 1 new var: `dialogType`